# GitHub Actions Environment variables for matrix-based testing

Tags: json, yaml, github-actions

I am struggling with the recent change on how GitHub Action Workflows defines runtime variables, [replacing the "set-ouput" approach with environment variables](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/).

Last summer, it took me a couple of hours to figure out the code below working for my requirement. Define a matrix of OS and python versions, so that the CI workflow can create corresponding environments and run the pytests on it.

Is there any chance to get support on how to best transform to the new approach?

```
env:
  # JSON variables (used in our strategy/matrix)
  SUPPORTED_PYTHON_VERSIONS: '\"python-version\":[\"3.8\", \"3.9\"]'
  SUPPORTED_OPERATING_SYSTEMS: '\"os\":[\"ubuntu-latest\", \"macos-latest\", \"windows-latest\"]'

jobs:
  # The set-env job translates the json variables to a usable format for the workflow specifications.
  set-env:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      py-os-matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix-vars.outputs.py-os-matrix }}
      # ^ this represents:
      # matrix:
      #   - os: [ubuntu-latest, ...]
      #   - python-version: [3.7, ...]
      os-matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix-vars.outputs.os-matrix }}
      # ^ this represents:
      # matrix:
      #   - os: [ubuntu-latest, ...]
    steps:
      - id: set-matrix-vars
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=py-os-matrix::{${{ env.SUPPORTED_PYTHON_VERSIONS }},${{ env.SUPPORTED_OPERATING_SYSTEMS }}}"
          echo "::set-output name=os-matrix::{${{ env.SUPPORTED_OPERATING_SYSTEMS }}}"

  test-run:
    name: test on ${{ matrix.os }} - ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    needs: set-env
    strategy:
      fail-fast: true
      matrix: ${{ fromJson(needs.set-env.outputs.py-os-matrix) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, a more elegant way of using the matrix keyword functions is available. My new implementation is much cleaner and, most important, avoids the above-mentioned deprecated function of printing env variables to `stdout`. However, the point is open how to integrate python versions >=3.10 ...

```
 jobs:
  test-run:
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest, windows-latest]
        python-version: [3.8, 3.9]
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install python
        id: setup-python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
          check-latest: true
```

Every further step which comes after the one with `setup-python` is executed in the currenlty selected combination of OS and python.